# ChartJS: Bar chart with axis ticks wider than categories

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to display a timeseries as a bar chart.  Is there some way to separate the tick resolution on the x axis from the width of the bars?

The snippet below demonstrates the problem; it is showing hourly data over one week.  Because `options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit` is set to `day`, the tick marks appear one per day but the bars are also one day wide.  Setting the unit to `hour` makes the bars the right width but leads to hundreds of tick marks on the x axis and makes the labels unreadable.

Is there some way to have the best of both?

```js
const RANGE = (a,b) => Array.from((function*(x,y){
  while (x <= y) yield x++;
})(a,b));

labels = [];
for(var ii = 0; ii < 170; ii++) {
  labels.push((1483228800 + ii * 3600) * 1000);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('chart'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    startingData = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
          {
              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: RANGE(1, 170),
              label: 'Data'
          },
      ]
    }, 
    options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'day',
          }
        }]
      }
    };

// Reduce the animation steps for demo clarity.
var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: startingData,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Hello, world.<br>
  <canvas id="chart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `unitStepSize` might be what you are looking for.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L15kdLnp/) is a JSFiddle with a example

As per the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#configuration-options):

> The number of units between grid lines.